# sql query for string contains in C#

Tags: sql

how to write sql query to do String contains operation.?

Consider,

```
string strTest = "Hash.System.Data.DataSet has.ds";
string str1 = "Hash.System.Data.DataSet has(System.Collections.Hashtable, Int32).ds";
string str2 = "Hash.System.Data.DataSet has(System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Collections.Hashtable).ds";
```

Here 
1)if i compare strTest with str1 it should return true.
2)if i compare strTest with str2 it should return true.

i.e i can ignore the part of string which is enclosed within '(' and ')'.

edit:
i'm trying to access MS access table using C# and need to check such conditions.

i need to check everything in 'strTest' excluding the part of string contained in brackets with str1 and str2.

str1 and str2 are entries in MS access table.

```
myCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT TableName FROM HashTableConfig WHERE ItemIdentity LIKE '" + strTest + "'";
```

This is the query where i should do changes so that it satisfies condition 1 and 2. ItemIdentity can have values like str1 and str2.

Comment: What exactly are you asking and what does it have to do with SQL? This looks like C#. Do you just want to compare strings and ignore anything within matching parentheses?

Comment: PATINDEX() if I understand the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
field LIKE 'Hash.System.Data.DataSet has(%).ds'
```